# How can I make a window lose its focus?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, focus

How can I make a window lose its focus just like when I minimize a window?
I tried `SetForegroundWindow(GetNextWindow(hWnd, GW_HWNDNEXT));`
but it didn't work. It seemed that the HWND gotten by GetNextWindow was wrong.
So can I improve it?

I don't want to use `ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE); ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOWNA)`, because it leads to an animation on taskbar in windows 7.

Are there any other perfect methods?

Comment: Maybe set focus to the desktop window.

Comment: What is `hWnd`? Depending on whether this is a top-level window or a child window, the handle returned by `GetNextWindow` will reference either a top-level window or a child window. You cannot call `SetForegroundWindow` on a child window.

Comment: This is a humdinger of an XY question.  As posted, the only correct answer is "don't do it".

Answer (score 0):

**GW_HWNDNEXT** specifies a window below another window. As stated [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (*msdn*),

> If there is **no next** (or previous) window, the return value is NULL. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.

Consequently, no other *hWnd* in the *Z-Order* is retrieved, hence the "wrong" *hWnd* value (It's NULL actually).

Comment: Well, the wrong hWnd was not NULL actually.  It seemed that I SetForegroundWindow something that can't be activated.

Comment: Well, I suppose `ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_MINIMIZE);` is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

Why not this?

```
ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_MINIMIZE);
```

There is another flag: `SW_FORCEMINIMIZE`